# How to banning insert to a tree?

Tags: java, tree

I want use the Ordered Linked `List:{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};` insert to a tree.

```
Left:
lve1  1
lve2     2
lve3        3
lve4           4
lve5              5 
lve6                 6
lve7                    7

right
lve1         4
lve2     2        6
lve3  1     3  5     7
```

Assuming already have a tree class.
If I am go
 `add(1), add(2), add(3)`....
One by one to add each, I will get the left tree.

Otherwise, I go `add(4), add(2), add(6), add(1), add(3)`.. by manually

[1,2,3,**4**,5,6,7]

[1,**2**,3,4,5,**6**,7]

[**1**,2,**3**,4,**5**,6,**7**]

I will get right one. more balance..

So, How Can I do it automatic in Java?

Comment: People are downvoting because it's completely unclear what you're asking. Please read the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page and take another shot at it.

Answer (score -2):

There is no automatic possibility in Java. The keyword you are searching for is "balancing" (a tree) and you will have to build it on your own.
Check this site, it has a more generalized description of a binary tree, yet just imagine you have simple nodes containing only one number -
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/33balanced/

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.